# Libreoffice writer incorrectly applying dark mode

Tags: themes, libreoffice, fonts, colors, 21.04

I don't know if you are going to understand me. I put the font color in options -> application colors in white and page color to gray (to make a dark theme), but when I try to color the table border it doesn't change to white, it stays black, the same when I change the text color to black, it changes it. Dark mode of office do the right thing changing the font color to white in black tables and text even selecting the text and making it black. In the image all of the text is black. The question is, how to enable a GOOD dark mode?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not see Options -> Color settings in my version of LibreOffice. Your final sentence, "how to make a GOOD dark mode", is also unclear to me. What is good for you may not be good for me. Indeed, your first disclaimer may be correct: you may need to clarify further what you are looking for.

Comment: Its not changing to white the black text when is black (only changing in automatic black) and it's not changing to white the table. It's not a good dark mode, MS office effectively change the black colors to white.

Comment: That is more clear. Incorporate this comment at the start of your question, and the question will immediately be more clear for everybody.